# My Long pending confusion on multi-threading in Java. Need help

Tags: java, multithreading

I am having this doubt about multi-threading and I have faced lots of questions about in multi-threading in many of the interviews.

I speak a lot of about acquiring a lock on the object as such. My doubt is when you have two methods that are synchronized and there are two threads which wants to access those two methods, ThreadA wants to access MethodA and ThreadB wants to access MethodB.

Now both the methods are in the same object. But I use to say acquiring lock on an object and i have not heard acquiring lock on a method. Now Can both the threads parallely access MethodA and MethodB? My assumption is once you acquire lock on object, no other thread on work on it. Isnt it?

And what is the significance synchronized(XYZ.class)?

Comment: Concurrency issues confuse the life out of me too. This article helped me a little http://www.vogella.de/articles/JavaConcurrency/article.html . It sounds like the second on the volatile vs synchronised keywords might help you out

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, they cannot. If I understand you correctly then you mean:

```
class Foo {

   public synchronized void methodA () {
      doSmth ();
   }

   public synchronized void methodB () {
      doSmthElse ();
   }

}
```

In this case synchronized modifier is equal to:

```
class Foo {

   public void methodA () {
      synchronized (this) {
         doSmth ();
      }
   }

   public void methodB () {
      synchronized (this) {
         doSmthElse ();
      }
   }

}
```

This means that only 1 thread can work at the same time inside one of these 2 methods on each Foo-object.

> And what is the significance synchronized(XYZ.class)?

That's what you have behind the scenes of

```
class XYZ {
   public static synchronized void someMethod () { ... }
}
```

Comment: So, its highly not recommended to put a synchronized keyword on the method. Isnt it?

Comment: In general case, YES. It's not because synchronized methods are bad. If all lines of your small method are not thread-safe (i.e. synchronization is necessary) then synchronized method is probably what you really need. But if you can put only part of the method into synchronized {} block then this approach should be used and you should avoid synchronized methods in this case.

Comment: One more doubt I am having regarding this synchronized(XYZ.class). You mean to say that whoever accesses someMethod() will acquire a lock on the whole class and all the instances of that class would not be accessible. Is it ?

Comment: All _static_ _synchronized_ methods of XYZ class and all code inside _synchronized_ _(XYZ.class)_ will not be accessible.

Comment: Strictly speaking, anything that acquires a monitor on XYZ.class will not be accessible. Since XYZ.class is a globally accessible reference, who knows what that could be? This is why it's a better practice to synchronize on private references.

Answer (score 5):

Declaring a method as synchronized is basically the same as containing the entire method body in a "synchronized(this) { ... }" block. So the lock on synchronized method is on the entire object instance, meaning that you are locking out others who want to use synchronized methods on that same object.
If you want per method synchronization instead of per object synchronization you will have to synchronize on something else, either by using synchronized(guardObject) in that particular method or by using one of the [Lock](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html) objects in java (most of them added in 1.5).

> And what is the significance synchronized(XYZ.class)?

This means that you are using the class as a guard object, it means that the lock in the class itself (not the instance) will be protecting access to the block. The difference to using the object instance as a guard is that if you have ten thousand objects you will only be able to access one of them at a time, compared to protecting access by more than one thread to an instance at a time.

Answer (score 3):

If methodA and methodB use different data structures, and it's safe to call methodA while somebody else is calling methodB, then those two methods should use *different locks*.

Here's the skinny on synchronized(XYZ.class)

synchronized (XYZ.class) is how you implment the above pattern -- it's a synchronized block that:

- acquires a lock on an object (in this class the instance of java.lang.class that represents XYZ)
- does some work
- releases the lock.

The key is to remember that every object in Java has a lock (the technical term is a *monitor*) that can be held by only one thread at a time. You can request the lock for any object that you have a reference to.

The synchronized keyword on a method:

```
public synchronized void foo() {
    //do something
}
```

is just syntactic sugar for this:

```
public void foo() {
    synchronized(this) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

There is one significant drawback to this approach: since anyone with a reference to an object can acquire its lock, synchronized methods won't work properly if an external caller acquires and holds the object lock.

(Incidentally, this is why locking on XYZ.class is also a bad idea: it's a globally accesible object, and you never know who might decide to acquire its lock)

To avoid these drawbacks, this pattern is usually used instead of the synchronized method:

```
private final Object LOCK = new Object();
public void foo() {
    synchronized(LOCK) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Since no external caller can have a reference to the LOCK object, only this class can acquire its lock, and the synchronized method will always work as expected.

When you have two different methods that need to be locked separately, the usual way to do that is for each method to lock on a different privately held object:

```
private final Object LOCKA = new Object();
private final Object LOCKB = new Object();
public void foo() {
    synchronized(LOCKA) {
        //do something
    }
}

public void bar() {
    synchronized(LOCKB) {
        //do something else
    }
}
```

Then it's possible for a thread to call foo() while another thread is calling bar(), but only one thread will be able to call foo() at a time, and only one thread will be able to call bar() at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Using `synchronized(XYZ.class)` is very restrictive. This means whatever code is being guarded by this `XYZ.class` will be executed by one thread only at the same time. You should be aware of this as it could lead to severe starvation problem.

Answer (score 0):

A thread entering into monitor on entrance to critical section defined as 'synchronized'
So you can define each method (not the whole class) as synchronized or even a code block within a method.
http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html